# Postgres - order records based on a property inside an array of json objects

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sql-order-by

I'm working with a Postgres database and I have a `products` view like this:

| id | name | product_groups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | [{...}] |
| 2 | product2 | [{...}] |

the `product_groups` field contains an array of json objects with the product groups data that the product belongs to, where each json object has the following structure:

```json
{
  "productGroupId": 1001,
  "productGroupName": "Microphones"
  "orderNo": 1,
}
```

I have a query to get all the products that belong to certain group:

```sql
SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p.product_groups @> [{"productGroupId": 1001}]
```

but I want to get all the products ordered by the `orderNo` property of the group that I'm querying for.

what should I add/modify to my query in order to achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve. Sort the elements of the array? Sort the resulting rows based on the orderNo of the matching productgroup? What if a product has more than one group? Do you want the matching group(s) to be returned as rows?

Answer (score 2):

You have to unnest the array:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(p.product_groups) AS arr(elem)
WHERE arr.elem @> '{"productGroupId": 1001}'
ORDER BY CAST(arr.elem ->> 'orderNo' AS bigint);
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without the join? 
I'm working on a project where we have a custom query builder but it can't do joins, I know it's something that needs to be improved but for now I'm just lookin' for a workaround.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid that. It is better not to use JSON to store regular tabular data.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure I understand your question. My assumptions are:

- there will only be one match for the condition on product groups
- you want to sort the result rows from the `products` table, not the elements of the array.

If those two assumptions are correct, you can use a JSON path expression to extract the value of `orderNo` and then sort by it.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p 
WHERE p.product_groups @> [{"productGroupId": 1001}]
ORDER BY jsonb_path_query_first(p.product_groups, '$[*] ? (@.productGroupId == 1001).orderNo')::int
```

Comment: I know this has been inactive for a while, but today I tried this query and it thrown the following error - 

ERROR: function jsonb_path_query_first(jsonb, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

According to what the error says I guess that I should manually cast the json_path string but how can I achieve this?